# Reactive Threading Exception: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm using the following code

```
    public IObservable<Unit> RunReport()
    {
        return Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            string selectedPath = null;

            //System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
            //{
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    selectedPath = ofd.FileName;
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedPath = null;
                }
            //});
        });
    }
```

which throws a `The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this` exception.

If i uncomment the 3 lines above then I don't get the exception, but this doesn't feel like the right way to fix this as many other answers I have seen regarding Observables and threading issues recommend using `Observable.Start(() => ...).ObserveOnDispatcher();`.

I have tried that option but the error remains!

Comment: What's the point of this code? This isn't observing any events. The fix is to use a scheduler that runs on the UI thread,( eg DispatcherScheduler.Instance). That's what ObserveOnDispatcher() does *for the observer*. In this case though, `Start()` deals with the observable/publisher. You can do the same thing though simply by removing the observable.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid reply! I've merely provided a minimal example of my problem. The `Observable<Unit>` function is used to create a custom `ReactiveCommand`, the implementation of which requires the code to be contained in an `Obervable.Start(...)`. The code resides in a ViewModel (I actually use a service to spawn the `OpenFileDialog`). I've tried `ObserveOnDispatcher` but the exception doesn't go away!

Comment: There's no *observer* here, so `ObserveOnDispatcher` has no effect. The dialog is displayed by the *starting observable event*. You need to add a scheduler to `Start`, ie `Start(...,DispatcherScheduler.Instance)`. That dialog is essentially a view though, not something that should be shown explicitly by a Command

Comment: Ok. That works, thanks. So if my command requires a user to select a file, how can i do that without it being explicitly shown by a command (my production code uses `IDialogService`). Also, I'm obviously still not 100% on the observer/dispatcher side of things, I don't suppose you can recommend any good resources? Thanks again :0)

Comment: RxApp.MainThreadScheduler is often better since it's platform aware. Eg hour view model will work on wpf of xamarin forms without change.